# After restart container going to exited state because address is already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Every time my container starts it goes into the exited state. When I inspect the container I see the error "address is already in use". To fix this I have to run docker-compose down and bring it up again. Is there a better solution because it should autostart the container.

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  app:
    image: test
    container_name: test
    environment:
      driver: ${driver}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "44379:443"
    networks:
      app-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.22.0.6
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -sSk https://localhost:443/health || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 15s
      start_period: 60s
      retries: 2

networks:
  app-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.22.0.0/16
```

Nginx proxy on the machine

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name  example.com  www.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl_certificate.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/sslprivate_key.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.158.0.150:44379;
  }
}
```

PS: I can manually clear the port but I am looking for a way so container can always auto starts without manually intervention

Comment: Uhm, any idea why it says address already in use?